# Is there a quick way to compute Fourier Series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Computing Fourier Series is often a lengthy and boring process for me. It often requires a couple of integration by parts, messy substantiations, etc. I know there are some ways to quickly compute Fourier Series for even and odd functions, and also there is a theorem for functions that are in the form $g(x) = af_1 + bf_2$, but these are special cases. There are plenty of function out there that are not even and/or odd and also not in the form $g(x) = af_1 + bf_2$. I am looking for some magical way that can lead me to the answer very quickly (something like Laplace transform table). Is there a similar thing for Fourier Series?

Comment: every function is in the form $af_1 + bf_2$

Comment: What classes of functions are you computing the Fourier series for? There certainly are tables, but it depends on what you're transforming.